# Can I scale all supervisor processes independently?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, supervisord

Say I have 3 services A, B & C in my project (Node.js).

I am running all these services in one container using supervisord.

Now when I push my container to tools like Kubernetes.

Can I create different number of replicas for these services ?

Ex. 10 replicas of A, 5 Replicas of B, 4 replicas of C

Comment: See http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#program-x-section-settings `numprocs`, but that whole solution is very counter-docker and kubernetes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Kubernetes, when you scale an application, you do it by creating some number of identical pods; each pod usually contains exactly one container; and Kubernetes doesn't really know what's running inside a container.  If the container runs supervisord running one copy of A, one copy of B, and one copy of C, then Kubernetes scaling can create 5x(1A+1B+1C), but it can never adjust settings in the supervisord configuration to have different numbers of the processes.

Usually you want to avoid running multiple processes in a container, and this is one of the key reasons why.  Run three separate containers (in Kubernetes, three separate Deployments) running one process each, and you can set the `replicas:` on each separately.

Comment: What happens when I want to start processes on demand (from an app) instead of keeping them fixed in Kubernetes Deployment or StatefulSet manifest? As @zerkms pointed maybe supervisord is not the best tool for it? I just wanted to check how flexible supervisord is. BTW, I agree that the answer to original question makes sense to split services to separate Deployments. The app has fixed need, fixed processes count.